# django.admin.SimpleListFilter.queryset - return list?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I would like to filter a queryset by a function in the model.

```
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class PostedByGuestFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

        title = 'Posted by Guest'
        parameter_name = 'posted_by_guest'

        def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
            return (
                (True, 'Yes'),
                (False, 'No'),
            )

        def queryset(self, request, queryset):
            if self.value():
                return [comment for comment in queryset if comment.posted_by_guest()]
            elif not self.value():
                return [comment for comment in queryset if not comment.posted_by_guest()]
```

Unfortuneately, this implemenation results in `django.admin` telling me that my database is corrupt. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It’s not optimal (will result in an extra SQL query), and I’d be looking for ways to move the `comment.posted_by_guest()` logic into SQL if possible (show the body of that method if you’d like help with that), but this ought to work:

```
def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    expected_value = self.value()
    excludes = []
    for comment in queryset:
        if comment.posted_by_guest() != expected_value:
            excludes.append(comment.id)
    return queryset.exclude(pk__in=excludes)
```

The Django admin filter API could do with some improvement!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that Django is expecting a queryset and your code is providing a list. You can fix this by wrapping your comprehension in a set:

```
    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return set(comment for comment in queryset if comment.posted_by_guest())
        elif not self.value():
            return set(comment for comment in queryset if not comment.posted_by_guest())
```